# Inequality related with concave property

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Assume that $f>0,f'<0$ and $f$ is logconcave(the log of $f$ is concave) and twice differentiable. Can we prove, or give a counter example to the following claim:

there exists $\bar x>0$ such that $F(x)=f(x)+xf'(x)\leq 0$ for all $x>\bar x$?

I've been struggling with this for a whole day... Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I have been able to prove that $F$ is quasiconcave. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: I guess $f$ is defined on $(0,\infty)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is logconcave and $f>0$, we can write $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$ where $g$ is concave. Obviously, $f'<0$ is equivalent to $g'<0$. Note that

$$F(x):=f(x)+x f'(x) \leq 0$$

if, and only if, $$\log(f(x)) \leq \log(-x \cdot f'(x))$$ by the monotonicity of the logarithm. Using that $f(x)=e^{g(x)}$, we see that this is equivalent to $$x^{-1} \leq -g'(x).$$

This means that it suffices to show that $$-x^{-1} \geq g'(x)$$ for $x$ sufficiently large. This follows from the following lemma (set $h=g'$ and recall that $g'$ is decreasing as $g$ is concave):

> **Lemma** Let $h:(0,\infty) \to (-\infty,0)$ be a monoton decreasing function. Then $$h(x) \leq - \frac{1}{x}$$ for $x$ sufficiently large.

*Proof:* Pick any $x_0>0$.Then, by assumption $h(x_0)<0$. In particular, $h(x) \leq h(x_0)<0$ for $x \geq x_0$. Since $-\frac{1}{x} \uparrow 0$ as $x \to \infty$, we have $$- \frac{1}{x} \geq h(x_0) \geq h(x)$$ for $x \geq x_1$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @Mathlover Yes, sorry; hopefully it's fine now.